# does Spark unpersist() have different strategy?

Tags: apache-spark, caching, persist

Just did some experiment on spark unpersist() and feel confused on what it actually did. I googled a lot and almost all people say the unpersist() will immediately evict the RDD from excutor's memory. but in this test, we can see it's not always ture. see the simple test below:

```
private static int base = 0;
public static Integer[] getInts(){
    Integer[] res = new Integer[5];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        res[i] = base++;
    }
    System.out.println("number generated:" + res[0] + " to " + res[4] + "---------------------------------");
    return res;
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("spark test").getOrCreate();
    JavaSparkContext spark = new JavaSparkContext(sparkSession.sparkContext());

    JavaRDD<Integer> first = spark.parallelize(Arrays.asList(getInts()));
    System.out.println("first: " + Arrays.toString(first.collect().toArray()));  // action
    first.unpersist();
    System.out.println("first is unpersisted");

    System.out.println("compute second ========================");
    JavaRDD<Integer> second = first.map(i -> {
        System.out.println("double " + i);
        return i*2;
    }).cache();  // transform
    System.out.println("second: " + Arrays.toString(second.collect().toArray()));  // action
    second.unpersist();

    System.out.println("compute third ========================");
    JavaRDD<Integer> third = second.map(i -> i+100);  // transform
    System.out.println("third: " + Arrays.toString(third.collect().toArray()));  // action
}
```

the output is:

```
number generated:0 to 4---------------------------------
first: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
first is unpersisted
compute second ========================
double 0
double 1
double 2
double 3
double 4
second: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
compute third ========================
double 0
double 1
double 2
double 3
double 4
third: [100, 102, 104, 106, 108]
```

As we can see, unpersist() 'first' is useless, it will not recalculate.
but unpersist() 'second' will trigger recalculation.
Anyone can help me to figure out why unpersist() 'first' will not trigger recalculation? if I want to force 'first' to be evicted out of memory, how should I do? is there any special for RDD from parallelize or textFile() API?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This behavior has nothing to do with caching and `unpersisting`. In fact `first` is not even `persisted`, although it wouldn't make much difference here.

When you `parallelize`, you pass a local, non-distributed object. `parallelize` takes its argument *by value* and its life cycle is completely out of Spark's scope. As a result Spark has no reason to recompute it at all, once `ParallelCollectionRDD` has been initialized. If you want to distribute different collection, just create a new `RDD`.

It is also worth noting that `unpersist` can be called in both blocking and non-blocking mode, depending on the `blocking` argument.